# Invalid token format error on use Telegram.bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I use this code for send a message.

```
var bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api("3bd8d2839afbb0ba2c0067578b7b0bc2");
var t = bot.SendTextMessage("@chanelName", "Hi ! Admin ");
```

but get me error:

> Invalid token format

App api_hash = 3bd8d2839afbb0ba2c0067578b7b0bc2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token format should look like this : 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#authorizing-your-bot

Try to add an id or something like a number before your token, for example:

```
xxxxxxxxx:3bd8d2839afbb0ba2c0067578b7b0bc2
```

where `xxxxxxxxx` is your id.

Or generate a new token with command `/token` : https://core.telegram.org/bots#generating-an-authorization-token

Comment: I create web app and then give this token

Answer (score 0):

your bot token is not valid.
if you didn't have your token just get it from bot father and put in your API object.
you don't need `api_hash` all you need is your bot token.